# "template argument 2 is invalid"-Error when I declare a list with a home made class

Tags: c++, class, templates, arguments

"template argument 2 is invalid"-Error when I declare a list with a home made class

```
include <list>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    class user
    {
        public: string name, pass;
        int droits;
};
list<user> user_list;
```

The global message error is 
*Multiple markers at this line
    - template argument 2 is invalid
    - trying to instantiate 'template class std::allocator'
    - template argument for 'template class std::allocator' uses local type 
     'main()::user'*
I'm getting started in C++ 
thanks for your help

Comment: Move class user out of main

Comment: In C++98, template parameter must not be a local type

Comment: Don't declare classes in function scope.